# Replace one coupon to another after coupon added

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have two coupons, one $10 another $5. I want do next, if price be less $50 and customer enter discount coupon $10 replace this coupon by coupon $5.

**Example:**

The customer added an item in cart with total price $40 and he applied the coupon $10-Off. Now I need replace current coupon with $10-Off to my another coupon $5-Off and continue checkout.

What is the best and simple way I can use? I try change discount price like in code below and this working, but in other places WC show me old coupon and calculate all data from old coupon (in order page etc) so I really need **REPLACE** one coupon to another ( not calculate their price ) when this coupon added. It like customer enter $5-Off coupon directly to discount field

```
// Change price for discount
if( ! function_exists('custom_discount') ){

  function custom_discount( $price, $values, $instance ) {

    //$price represents the current product price without discount
    //$values represents the product object
    //$instance represent the cart object

    //Get subtotal
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $coupon = WC()->cart->get_discount_total();

    //if price < 50 and we have active coupon then we need decrease price to $5
    if( $subtotal < 50 && ! empty( WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() ) ){
      $price = $subtotal  - 5; //Wrong way ...
    }
    return $price;
  }

  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'custom_discount', 10, 3);

}
```

Comment: Can't you just create coupon **with a minimum spend** of for example, $50 as in the question? I mean, that can be easily set when you create the coupon.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you for comment. I already have two coupons $5 (not public, nobody know about this coupon) and $10 (public, users can use it). I want check if price < $50, and user try use coupon of $10, replace this coupon to smaller coupon to not allow user use $10 coupon for price which be less then $50

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the minus of question?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't downvote the question or the current answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires to use an action hook like `woocommerce_calculate_totals` that is related to cart and **Ajax enabled**, because it will handle all changes made by the customer in cart page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'discount_based_on_cart_subtotal', 10, 1 );
function discount_based_on_cart_subtotal( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Avoiding hook repetitions
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Your coupons settings below
    $coupon_05_off = '$5-Off';
    $coupon_10_off = '$10-Off';

    // When cart subtotal is below 50
    if ( $cart->subtotal < 50 ) {
        if ( $cart->has_discount( $coupon_10_off ) ) {
            $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_10_off ); // Remove $10.00 fixed discount coupon
            if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_05_off ) ) {
                 $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_05_off ); // Add $5.00 fixed discount coupon
            }
        }

    }
    // When cart subtotal is up to 50
    else {
        if ( $cart->has_discount( $coupon_05_off ) ) {
            $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_05_off ); // Remove $5.00 fixed discount coupon
            if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_10_off ) ) {
                $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_10_off ); // Add $10.00 fixed discount coupon
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: I think hook `woocommerce_calculate_totals` more correct instead `woocommerce_before_cart` in previous answer. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like it will add a coupon even if the customer didn't have the $10 code already?

Comment: @Rup good point, I think we need remove last `if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_10_off ) )` because if user not enter any coupon it always will get $10 coupon right?

Comment: @BrotheryuraUpdated my code… It should work now as you expect.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec now all fine thank you, I will mark this answer like right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and can confirm that it works, even after you change the products in the cart to be either below or over $50.

```
<?php
/**
 * @snippet Add / Remove A Coupon Dynamically based on Cart Subtotal with WooCommerce
 * @sourcecode http://wpharvest.com
 * @author Dragos Micu
 * @compatible WooCommerce 2.4.7
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'wpharvest_apply_coupons' );
function wpharvest_apply_coupons($cart) {
    global $woocommerce;
    // Set your coupon codes
    $coupon10off = '$10-Off';
    $coupon5off = '$5-Off';

    // Get the cart subtotal
    $cart_subtotal = $cart->subtotal;
    // If cart subtotal is less than 50 add or remove coupons
    if ($cart_subtotal < 50) {
        if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon10off ) ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon10off );
            $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon5off );
        }
    }
    // If cart subtotal is greater 49 add or remove coupons
    if ($cart_subtotal > 49 ) {
        if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon5off ) ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon5off );
            $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon10off );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the minus?

Comment: hi thx for your answer, I don't know who minus your answer like minus my question too, I will check soon your variant. In first view it must working. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again @Dragos Micu, your answer very good and working, but `LoicTheAztec` has more detailed answer, hope next time I will select your answer!